# Convert char array to single element Matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I am retrieving file names of Images in a array as:

```
image_files = dir(strcat(dir_path, '\*' , img_extension));
s = image_files(j).name
```

Now I need to save names of images files in a file, but first I need to concatenate all the image names in a single matrix,

```
M = [M, s]
```

However since s is a character array, all the characters of file names will be treated as separate columns where as I need to treat a single file name as a single entity in M.

Is there any work around?

Comment: Try this maybe - `{image_files.name}`. It produces a cell array, if you are okay with it.

Comment: @Divakar then i wont be able to write this matrix, M, to a text file using dlmwrite() function....
is there any other way to write M to a text file even if it contains cell array elements....
thanks

Comment: `dlmwrite` doesn't support strings, only numeric data (the fact that it apparently _happens_ to work with `char` arrays is an undocumented feature) - you'd be far better off [using a cell array of strings](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/import_export/write-to-delimited-data-files.html#zmw57dd0e3630).

Answer (score 1):

Try this for PNG files in the working directory -

```
%%// Parameters
img_extension = '.png';
dir_path = pwd;
textfile = 'myFile.csv';

image_files = dir(strcat(dir_path,filesep,'*',img_extension));
x = {image_files.name};

fid=fopen(textfile,'wt');
[rows,cols]=size(x);
for i=1:rows
    %fprintf(fid,'%s,',x{i,1:end-1}); %%// Use comma separated file names
    fprintf(fid,'%s\n',x{i,1:end-1}); %%// Use newline separated file names
    fprintf(fid,'%s\n',x{i,end});
end
fclose(fid);
```

**Edit 1:** If you still need a char matrix or char arrays of the file names, choose from one of the following three outputs -

```
x = {image_files.name};
char_matrix1 = char(x{:}) %%// Create a MxN char matrix
char_array1  = strjoin(x,',') %%// Create a Mx1 char matrix separated by commas between filenames
char_array2  = strjoin(x,' ') %%// Create a Mx1 char matrix separated by spaces between filenames
```

**Note :** `strjoin` is available in the recent MATLAB version and on MATLAB file-exchange [here](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31862-strjoin).

Comment: Hi Divakar, it seems a good solution , however not applicable in my scenario, thanks...

Comment: @Zohaib Try the Edit 1.

Comment: Just use `filesep` (or `fullfile`) to construct platform-independent paths, not that nasty if-else setup.